# Azure: Frontdoor and storage account getting InvalidQueryParameterValue error on QueryParameterName `comp`

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-front-door

I am hosting a reactJS SPA as static webpage on storage account's `$web` container.

I have uploaded the build files already.
I have enabled static website and I have done all the things such that I can view the SPA from my browser when I enter the primary endpoint url: `https://myappjohndev1.z11.web.core.windows.net/`

Now, instead of letting users visit my website using this storage account endpoint url, I want to put Azure FrontDoor in front of it,  and users will visit the frontdoor instead.

The storage account static website is set as a backend in the frontdoor. Here are the full settings of the frontdoor:

The frontend / domains:

- configured to be: `https://devjohn1.azurefd.net`

The backend pool:

- Backend host type:  Custom host
- backend host name: `myappjohndev1.z11.web.core.windows.net`

I have also tried to configure the backend as:

- Backend host type:  Storage
- backend host name: select the storage account that is hosting the SPA now.

However, when I visit `https://devjohn1.azurefd.net`, I get this in the browser:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
<Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid. RequestId:4a8be0c9-701e-0055-60d8-b727f2000000 Time:2023-07-16T11:27:09.4837987Z</Message>
<QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName>
<QueryParameterValue/>
<Reason/>
</Error>
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here.
any suggestions?

Comment: @Dai  You are right. It was a typo. I have updated it

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: Change Origin Host Type to `Storage (Static Websites)`**

I had exact same error.  For me problem was that when I used Azure Portal to create the Azure Front End Profile, the origin host type was set to `Storage (Azure Blobs)` by default.  I just needed to set it to `Storage (Static Website)`. [Note: I'm using Azure Front Door Standard, no need for Premium for this].

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create Azure front door premium, you need to create private link service and WAF policy.

[image]

Create a WAF policy with Azure premium tier with detection mode:

[image]

In Azure front door select premium tier with custom origin type with static website host name and enable private link service with WAF policy like below:

[image]

[image]

Once front door created, in private link ***Approve*** the request in private endpoint connection like below

[image]

Updated NAT configuration:

[image]

Now, when I try to redirect azure front door URL with storage account static website is set as a backend in the front door got result successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Premium in APIM is just too expensive. We would not be able to use it.